# Trying to build a Qt project on a raspberry pi, why is it throwing errors about qmake?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, qt5, qmake

I have a C++ Qt 5 project that was written, tested, and built on a windows machine. It works perfectly there. I also have to make the project work on a Linux environment and I was handed a raspberry pi 3 model b. I managed to get Qt 5 on it (I think) and I definitely got Qt creator working on it. Whenever I try to build it, I get an error that states something along the lines of:

> Error while building/deploying project projectName (kit: Desktop) 
>   When executing step 'qmake'

I'm new to Qt and raspberry pi, can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install qt5-qmake qt5-qmake-bin build-essential` in a terminal.

Comment: I tried that and it said it couldn't locate qt5-make-bin, so I tried them individually. It said that qt5-qmake and build-essential were already their newest version and still could not locate the package for qt5-gmake-bin.

Comment: it is `qt5-qmake-bin` and not `qt5-make-bin` nor `qt5-gmake-bin`.

Comment: p.s. you can show your qmake file here also. Maybe it will help someone answer the question more precisely.

Comment: Ah my bad, I meant `qt5-qmake-bin`, just a lot of bad typos from me recently. But I did try it again just in case and it still cannot find the package for it. Also how do I post the qmake file here if it's a binary file? Though I also asked somebody else and they told me part of another way to do it is I take the .pro file and use `qmake -o makefile myProject.pro` to make the makefile and that succeeded as far as I can tell, it did make the make file. Problem now is I don't know what to do with the makefile. @JoeyMallone

Comment: He mentioned something about using `make` on it which I hope is wrong because when I did that with `make myProject` I got a lot of errors that were not in the windows version, might just be some stuff is linux specific but I sure hope not as it was a lot of errors that don't make sense to be popping up since the errors appeared to be Qt specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself. Turns out the kit wasn't seeing GCC so I had to add the GCC compiler in the settings and tell the kit to use GCC.